# When press browser back button cart is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

Its my first question so I am very excited to become part of this big community.

I am experiencing an issue with the cart.The point is when I press the browser back button after adding some product to my cart the cart appears empty. But when I reload the page the cart is now with the product I added before.

Is there any way to get the cart updated when I press the browser back button like when I refresh the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is coming from the browser cache and it's not a Magento bug, you have to add a back button in your next page pointing to the cart url `$this->getBaseUrl().'checkout/cart/'` so here you wi'll reload the **cart** page data from Magento instead of the **browser** cached one, **OR** maybe you have some cache in your Magento which also creates this issue !

Comment: Thank you Prince but I need to gete the cart when the user press the browser back button. I know is not Magento bug but, is not any way to store the cart in session and reload it when the browser back event is fired? Thank you!